# Understanding MPI_Type_vector

Tags: mpi

I expected the following code to produce `1,0,2,0`
but it produces `1,2,0,0`. Why doesn't it pad received data?

```
// tmp.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );

    int rk;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rk );

    if ( rk == 0 )
    {
        double b[2] = {1.0, 2.0};
        MPI_Send( b, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }
    if ( rk == 1 )
    {
        double b[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

        MPI_Datatype padded;
        MPI_Type_vector( 1, 1, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, &padded );
        MPI_Type_commit( &padded );

        MPI_Recv( b, 2, padded, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

        std::cout << b[0] << ',' << b[1] << ','
                  << b[2] << ',' << b[3] << '\n';

        MPI_Type_free( &padded );
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I change receive part to

```
        MPI_Datatype padded;
        MPI_Type_vector( 2, 1, 2, MPI_DOUBLE, &padded );
        MPI_Type_commit( &padded );

        MPI_Recv( b, 1, padded, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
```

it produces `1,0,2,0`.

---

MPI: OpenMPI 3.1.2

GCC: 7.2.1

Build:  `mpicxx tmp.cpp`

Run: `mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out`